# How to make Pandas aware of holiday dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking at the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

I have a dataframe which contains a daily time series (Note that 2013-03-29 is a holiday and `mydf` contains 2013-03-28).

```
import pandas as pd

business_month_end_dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-31', '2014-04-30', freq='BM')

business_month_end_dates

DatetimeIndex(['2010-02-26', '2010-03-31', '2010-04-30', '2010-05-31',
           '2010-06-30', '2010-07-30', '2010-08-31', '2010-09-30',
           '2010-10-29', '2010-11-30', '2010-12-31', '2011-01-31',
           '2011-02-28', '2011-03-31', '2011-04-29', '2011-05-31',
           '2011-06-30', '2011-07-29', '2011-08-31', '2011-09-30',
           '2011-10-31', '2011-11-30', '2011-12-30', '2012-01-31',
           '2012-02-29', '2012-03-30', '2012-04-30', '2012-05-31',
           '2012-06-29', '2012-07-31', '2012-08-31', '2012-09-28',
           '2012-10-31', '2012-11-30', '2012-12-31', '2013-01-31',
           '2013-02-28', '2013-03-29', '2013-04-30', '2013-05-31',
           '2013-06-28', '2013-07-31', '2013-08-30', '2013-09-30',
           '2013-10-31', '2013-11-29', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-31',
           '2014-02-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

I then create Business Year End Dates:

```
business_year_end_dates =  pd.date_range(business_month_end_dates[0],
                                 business_month_end_dates[len(business_month_end_dates)-1],
                                 freq=BYearEnd(month=3))

business_year_end_dates

DatetimeIndex(['2010-03-31', '2011-03-31', '2012-03-30', '2013-03-29',
           '2014-03-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BA-MAR')
```

My expected output is :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-03-31', '2011-03-31', '2012-03-30', '2013-03-28',
       '2014-03-31'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BA-MAR')
```

Should Pandas understand via `BM    business month end frequency` that the 2013-03-29 is a holiday?

If not how do I make Pandas aware such that when I use BM it uses the previous working day in this case 2013-03-28?

Comment: Holidays are extremely country-specific, so it's sensible that by default pandas doesn't include anything.  There is some example usage of Custom Business Days (to include the holidays you desire) on the very documentation page you cite.

Comment: It's "experimental", and there may not be a business year end yet, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessMonthEnd

index = pd.date_range('2010-01-31', '2014-04-30', freq='BM')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(len(index), 2), columns=['a', 'b'], index=index)

holidays = ['2013-03-29']

df = df.resample(rule=CustomBusinessMonthEnd(holidays=holidays)).last()

df = df.loc[df.index.month==3]
```

Output:

```
>>>df.index
>>>DatetimeIndex(['2010-03-31', '2011-03-31', '2012-03-30', '2013-03-28', '2014-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12CBM')
```